# checking if a pair of value is inside a 2D array python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given an array `arr` defined as follows

```
arr = np.arange(4).reshape((2,2))
```

I want to check if a pair of value [0,1] for exemple is inside my array

I tried np.isin() but it consider the pair of value as two individual value. anyone knows a way to fix this?

Comment: Show us the exact code you used, and the output it produced.  Telling us that you "tried" a function doesn't tell us that you did it _right_.

Comment: np.isin(arr, [0,1]) is the way I did it, it returns ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply run

```
print([0,1] in arr)
```

to see if `[0,1]` exists in the first level loop. It should return `True` in the example you have provided

Comment: This only works if `[0,1]` is a discrete element of `arr`.  I think he's wanting to find _any adjacent pair of elements_.

Answer (score 3):

not sure what previously written was what OP wanted

try this

```
([0,1] == arr).all(axis = 1).any()
```

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me. The other two answers still considered the pair as individual numbers. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
np.any(my_array[:, 0] == value)
```